PDF rendering issues with multilingual text across different languages in a PDF generation library like pdf-lib
I am generating PDFs in my project using libraries such as @react-pdf/renderer and pdf-lib, and I am encountering significant challenges with font compatibility for multilingual text. In my use case, parts of the PDF may contain content in language A (e.g., Korean), while other parts are in language B (e.g., English). I have attempted to use fonts like Helvetica, Roboto, and Noto, but certain characters from various languages or scripts either fail to render or result in inaccurate glyphs.
Additionally, even when a PDF renders the text correctly, copying and pasting the content elsewhere often results in gibberish, likely due to mismatched glyphs or incorrect Unicode encoding. This issue becomes particularly problematic since the text content is dynamically fetched from a backend API, where messages are iterated over to build the PDF.
I am looking for a solution or a recommendation for a font that can seamlessly handle multilingual text—including complex scripts like Korean, Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, and Hindi—while maintaining accurate rendering and proper Unicode mapping for copy-paste functionality. Ideally, the solution should not require extensive fallback font configurations or embedding multiple font files. I have attached reference images to illustrate the issue further.
[![Here the text in different language is missing][1]][1]

Here the text in different language is missing

[![The numbers in the PDF are not rendered correctly, and when I attempt to copy and paste content in another language, the pasted text appears as gibberish.][2]][2]
2ND IMAGE

The numbers in the PDF are not rendered correctly, and when I attempt to copy and paste content in another language, the pasted text appears as gibberish.


The single font that has most languages is one of the Noto Fonts like Noto Sans as it supports 885 languages currently. But you can always load dynamic fonts as well.
Custom fonts are supported by @react-pdf/renderer and you can find ways how to use it in this answer.
An example:
import {
    Font,
} from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import NotoSans from './pdfFonts/noto-sans.ttf';

Font.register({
    family: 'Noto Sans',
    fonts: [
        {
            src: NotoSans,
        },
    ],
});

Then in a Text:
<Text
  style={{ fontFamily: 'Noto Sans' }}
>
  My text
</Text>


Now if it still not right you can register more languages and then use them dynamically:
//Register another font
Font.register({
    family: 'Noto Sans Japanese',
    fonts: [
        {
            src: NotoSansJapanese,
        },
    ],
});

//...
//Use
//Maybe create a map/enum... you get the idea
<Text
  style={{ fontFamily: isJapanese ? 'Noto Sans Japanese' : 'Noto Sans' }}
>
  My text
</Text>


Edit:
In the case of having different chars in a string the only way is to map each character. And render individually with a span. As react-pdf/renderer doesn't have span i will use a flex:
const CodeFamilies = {
    base: 'Noto Sans',
    japanese: 'Noto Sans Japanese',
};

// maps each code to some compatible family
function getFamily(code: number) {
    if (code > 1000) return CodeFamilies.base;
    if (code < 1000) return CodeFamilies.japanese;
    // and others....
}

function RenderText({ chars }: { chars: string[] }) {
    //lineHeighish...
    const lineheight = '1px';
    const letterspacing = '0px'
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                // wrap so it behaves like a normal text
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                rowGap: lineheight,
                columnGap: letterspacing
            }}
        >
            {chars.map((c, i) => {
                // get unicode code
                const code = c.charCodeAt(0);
                return (
                    <Text key={i} style={{ fontFamily: getFamily(code) }}>
                        {c}
                    </Text>
                );
            })}
        </View>
    );
}


Thank you
Yes, fontFamily: isJapanese ? 'Noto Sans Japanese' : 'Noto Sans' would have worked but my problem is some text in a sentence can be in english while some text in the same sentence can be in another language and i dont even know which text will be in which langauge.

@Shahed just edited with a possible solution.
